# Every new Registered user gets "invalid login attempt"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

So, I wanted to customize my code (working with the Microsoft docs) to allow users to set their own username, and from my knowledge this should function, however every time I register now as a new account and then try to log back in with the exact same information I receive the error

> invalid login attempt

and have no idea why. I've tried changing it so that the email is used as the username like it used to be, but it still comes up with the same error.

My current code:

```
usings...

namespace NameNameName.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 3)]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "User Name")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6b5c3c2-6086-46ff-be81-800d9a4d80a6/invalid-login-attempt-using-aspnet-identity?forum=aspmvc) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAOzR6XPXQg) Do these links help you?

Comment: [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAOzR6XPXQg) fixed it instantly! thank you so much! Is there anything I can do to credit your comment for this? @Jiale Xue - MSFT

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue. If there is a problem with it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment, the solution to resolve this question is to set the [`RequireConfirmedAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinoptions.requireconfirmedaccount?view=aspnetcore-6.0#definition) to `false`.

Refer to the following codes:

```
//This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add service to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServe(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnetion")));
  services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options=>options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount=false).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
  services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

Refer [Invalid Login Attempt .Net Core Razor Pages, MVC & Asp.Net Identity Project - OkTests.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAOzR6XPXQg) to resolve similar questions.